# How to refer a user variable in a script inside an SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I am using an SSIS package which has variables.

I am retrieving data from a progress data base and I want to refer one of the variables I am using in the Query string to filter data.

My question is what **is the syntax to be used** in order to refer this variable in the progress script

I tried this syntaxe 
@[User::uservaraibale] found in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/use-variables-in-packages?view=sql-server-2014) 
but it is not working

Suppose the script is

> select column1,column2 from Table where column3=@uservariable

How to refer **@uservariable** ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Initially Set the parameter mapping and then use ? in place of variable in sql script.
[image]

[image]